# Installing openSUSE via USB

Tags: system-installation, opensuse, usb-drive

Can anyone explain ***briefly*** how to install openSUSE via USB?

I searched in lot of forums, but I couldn't find anything helpful. Moreover, there was something written about installing it with the `dd_rescue` command, but that doesn't seem to work.

So please give me a brief idea for installing openSUSE via USB.

Answer (score 2):

If your BIOS supports 'boot from usb' as an option in the boot loader (cd, hdd, net, floppy etc).

You can create an bootable image on a usb drive. I've done so with Debian, but here is a howto for OpenSUSE I pulled from a search result that should apply to you.

http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Live_USB_stick

Once you have your image on the usb (note that it wipes your usb) just configure your bios, and reboot with the usb drive inserted. It should boot from the usb and continue with the install.

Comment: I did try it but that doesn't work.

Comment: Were you able to get the image written to the usb? When you explore the usb does it show various files associated to the image or is it blank? Did you you change the boot order so it boots from USB first? I'm sorry but *'that doesn't work'* isn't descriptive enough to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: During the boot up it says, operating system missing.

Comment: It seems there's an issue with writing the image from what I gather. Did you make the USB bootable as pointed out in the tutorial (bottom of the page)? If that fails, I'd recommend http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ as applies to all Linux based distros.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an image file for the suse install you want? Usually the process is:

1. Get install disk image, from http://en.opensuse.org/
2. Extract that image onto a USB drive (Izarc/7-zip wll do (in windows), or double click on the file in linux/unix. Or mount as a loopback and copypaste.)
3. Use a tool such as unetbootin or mkboot.bat (windows only) to make the drive bootable (you can google them)
4. Put the USB stick in the computer you want suse on, and make sure that computer can boot from usb drives, which could involve going into the bios.
5. follow instructions, assumign all went well.

That is the best I can do without more information such as the operating system(s) you have now, what kind of computer you want suse on and if that computer has any OS already.